Consuming third party REST services in Java - Who provides the POJO classes?
I am a bit new to consuming third party rest APIs using Spring Boot and Java. I have experience consuming REST APIs we have developed internal to our organization. When consuming rest APIs internal to our organization, the API owner also usually provides a "POJO" jar that we can use for mapping the API response.
When consuming third party REST APIs that are not owned by you or your org, you need to create the Java POJO model yourself for consuming the REST API response.
What is the approach that is normally followed for creating these domains. Does one try to understand the JSON response of the API and hand-code the domain models? Or do you use third party tools that can generate the domains by looking at the sample JSON responses? On similar lines, how does one know that an API supports HATEOS or not? It appears that being a consumer of an external REST API requires you to do a lot of work before you can consume the API.
For example, I was trying to use the BitBucket rest API to create some reports related to pull requests in my org. But turns out that I first need to create the domain objects before I can even get to generating the reports. Does BitBucket provide the domain model for their REST API already which we can simply use as a maven dependency? (For example, spring cloud data flow provides its POJOs publicly so it makes it easy for me to consume their APIs and use their POJOS instead of having to worry about creating the POJOs myself)

u pretty much just look at json and create urself a java class with matching fields. No need for some complicated tooling or autogeneration - there are some tools out there but IMO for majority of cases they add unnecessary complexity

Many third party APIs these days have swagger documentation, you can use Swagger to Java codegen tool to generate corresponding Java POJOs. for more info have a look here https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/master/modules/swagger-codegen-maven-plugin.
Looks like bitbucket APIs are also documented in swagger here https://api.bitbucket.org/swagger.json
